# Type mismatch error using custom class subroutine in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, class, excel, methods

Working in Excel VBA, I have a class module where I define my class 'Marker'. One of the properties of my class is TextLine(), which is an array that holds up to 5 strings. I have defined the two methods below in my class module. In another (regular) module, I fill `markerArr()` with my custom Marker objects. Loading each object's properties with data at each array index is working fine... However, after loading data into the object at each index, I try to use `markerArr(count).ProcessLines` but receive a type mismatch error. Since `ProcessLines` is a public sub in my class module, and `markerArr(count)` contains a Marker object, I can't seem to understand why this error is occurring... Am I overlooking something obvious?

```
'Serial number replacement processing function
Public Sub ProcessLines()

    Dim strSerial As String
    Dim toggle As Boolean
    toggle = False

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 4
        If Trim(m_TxtLines(i)) <> "" Then
            'Add linefeed char to non-empty text lines
            m_TxtLines(i) = m_TxtLines(i) & Chr(10)

            'Detect if it is a serialized line
            If InStr(1, m_TxtLines(i), "XXXXXX-YYY") > 0 Then
                m_Serial(i) = True
                toggle = True
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'When at least one line on the marker is serialized, create and replace serial text
    If toggle = True Then
        'Only prompt for input once
        If startSerNo < 1 And Num_Sers < 1 Then
            startSerNo = InputBox("Enter the serial number to start printing at." & Chr(10) & _
                "Entering 1 will result in -001, entering 12 will result in -012, etc.", "Starting Serial #", "1")

            Num_Sers = InputBox("Enter the amount of serializations to perform." & Chr(10) & _
                "This will control how many copies of the entire marker set are printed.", "Total Serializations", "1")
        End If

        strSerial = CreateSerial(startSerNo)

        Dim j As Integer
        For j = 0 To 4
            If m_Serial(j) Then
                m_TxtLines(j) = Replace(m_TxtLines(j), "XXXXXX-YYY", strSerial)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

'Creates the string to replace XXXXXX-YYY by concatenating the SFC# with the starting serial number
Private Function CreateSerial(ByVal startNum As Integer)
    Dim temp
    temp = SFC_Num

    Select Case Len(CStr(startNum))
        Case 1
            temp = temp & "-00" & startNum
        Case 2
            temp = temp & "-0" & startNum
        Case 3
            temp = temp & "-" & startNum
        Case Else
            temp = temp & "-001"
    End Select

    CreateSerial = temp
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your CreateSerial function takes an integer as a parameter, but you are attempting to pass a string. I've pointed out some problems:**

If startSerNo < 1 And Num_Sers < 1 Then ***'Here I assume, you have these semi-globals as a variant - you are using numeric comparison here***

startSerNo = InputBox("Enter the serial number to start printing at." & Chr(10) & _
                "Entering 1 will result in -001, entering 12 will result in -012, etc.", "Starting Serial #", "1") ***'Here startSerNo is returned as a string from the inputbox***

Num_Sers = InputBox("Enter the amount of serializations to perform." & Chr(10) & _
                "This will control how many copies of the entire marker set are printed.", "Total Serializations", "1") ***'here Num_Sers becomes a String too***

End If

strSerial = CreateSerial(startSerNo) ***'here you are passing a String to the CreateSerial function. Either pass an integer, or allow a variant as parameter to CreateSerial***

```
'......more code.....
```

Private Function CreateSerial(ByVal ***startNum As Integer***)